# How should I index a private vector from outside the class?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, std, size-t

Assuming a situation where I have:

```
class A {
private:
    std::vector<X> _v;
    // ...
public:
    A();
    // ...
};
```

and assuming I need to limit the access to the vector elements for editing and/or reading. What type of indexing (`int`, `long`, `std::size_t`, custom iterator or others) should I use to specify an element in the vector from outside the A class?

Is the following indexing correct?

```
class A {
    // ...
    X getVectorElement(std::size_t);
    void editSomeElementValue(std::size_t, double); // double is the type of the value to edit
};
```

What other options do I have?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the index type is `std::vector<T>::size_type`, although this is usually the same as `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `size_type` for the index - the same type as your vector:

```
// Make your own type for the index based on the vector's index type
typedef std::vector<X>::size_type size_type;
// Use your typedef in the declaration of your getter
X getVectorElement(size_type index);
```

Returning a copy is a good idea - in fact, it's the best thing to do if you want to hide the vector from your callers. Returning a pointer or a reference may be more performant, but it opens up your class to backdoor manipulations, in cases when `X` is mutable. It also creates an issue if the vector is modified after a reference has been returned, because changing the vector invalidates references to its elements.

You can provide individual functions for manipulating attributes of `X`, but you could also provide a setter that lets users replace an element of your vector.

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever best fits the design of your class. The fact that your class uses `std::vector` internally is irrelevant; class interfaces should not be driven by implementation details. Any adjustments, whether of values or types, can be done **inside** your class. So use `std::size_t`, `unsigned`, or whatever.

Comment: "class interfaces should not be driven by implementation details" - That is what made me think. Using `std::vector<X>::size_type` wouldn't really "hide" the implementation. Would `std::size_t` fit well then?

Answer (score 0):

`size_type` is a static member type of the type `std::vector<X>`

And it is a typedef for `std::size_t`, which itself is usually a typedef for `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`

So can use `std::vector<X>::size_type` or just `std::size_t` for indexing.